# Computed property gives wrong array length for $children

Tags: javascript, arrays, webpack, vue.js

I feel as if I am going insane. I have tested it in Firefox and Chrome and both have this issue so I don't think this is a browser-specific bug.

I have the following component:

```
<template lang="pug">
  #app
    img(src="./assets/logo.png")
    .titleArea(v-html="marked(question.title)")
    #answer
      answer-btn(v-for="(answer, index) in question.answers" :key="index" v-model="answer.selected" v-html="marked(answer.text)") 
    h3 {{ correct }}
</template>

<script>
import AnswerBtn from "./components/AnswerBtn.vue";
import marked from "marked";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      question: {
        title: "# Question Title",
        type: 2,
        answers: [
          {
            text: "Option 0",
            code: 0,
            selected: false
          },
          {
            text: "Option 1",
            code: 1,
            selected: false
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    correct() {
      window.abc = this.$children
      let ok = false;
      console.log("!!!!From Computed!!!!", this.$children, this.$children.length)
      this.validate();
      setTimeout(this.validate, 1)
      return ok;
    }
  },
  components: { AnswerBtn: {
      template: "<button>Hi</button>"
  } },
  methods: {
    marked,
    validate() {
      console.log("!!!!From Methods!!!!", this.$children, this.$children.length)
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This will generate two `AnswerBtn`s inside the app which can then be referred to as `$this.children` which is suppose to be a normal array which reports it's own length correctly. Sadly, that is not the case.

The order in which `console.log` will be called is as follows:

1: The `console.log` inside `correct()` will be called
2: The `console.log` inside `validate()` will be called (from `correct()`) 
3: The `console.log` inside `validate()` will be called 1ms later via `setTimeout`

In theory, I would expect the output to be the same in all 3 cases. Yet it is not. This what console.log outputs:

```
!!!!From Computed!!!! Array [] 0
!!!!From Methods!!!!  Array [] 0
!!!!From Methods!!!! Array [ {…}, {…} ] 2
```

So now you may be thinking that the children get somehow placed in 1ms after the computed function executed and not a moment earlier. That's reasonable, but wait! There's more!

[image: WTF]
[image: WTF]

In all cases, we can observe that the children are INDEED THERE! And the length inside the object is `2`. Yet trying to do anything in all cases except the last one with either the children or the length results in insanity.

Calling `this.$children.splice(0)` returns an empty array. `JSON.stringify(this.$children)` results in an empty array but as a string.

I have never seen an issue like this. Pls halp.

Comment: `console.log` is not synchronous. There *will* be times where something that looks weird like this will happen. You are far better off setting break points in the code.

Comment: It being async doesn't explain why the same console.log statement's output is inconsonstent, I am not calling the array and it's length separately.

Comment: No it just means chrome updated the contents of the object with same reference.

Comment: Oh my, that does make sense. So console.log doesn't output by value but by reference and within the time it took chrome to fetch the value, it had changed. Ahh, it all makes sense now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, partially. Computed values are computed BEFORE components are rendered.

The reason for the inconsistency between the expected `.length` and the actual `.length` is that console.log is async and logs by reference.

In other words, what I am actually outputting looks like this

`console.log(children*, int<0>)` (Pointer to the children array and the number 0) when children is empty. In turn, within the next 1ms, children gets it's two elements only after which the browser fetches the value of children and finds that it's an array with two elements.